# tornado realtime stream from twitter, uimodules & async db

Tags: twitter, tornado, mongoengine

I'm working on my first tornado project and i have some questions :

1- apart of the project is collecting and categorize  real time hash-tags and tweets form different twitter users is and put them on the website I want ti use iostream for realtime results is there libraries helping me to do that and how to use it I found libs like python-twitter , tweepy but I don't know what is the best and I red about twitter limited api so what is library / way to do that? ... sorry but It's my first time to work with twitter too

2- I found in tornado documentation UIModule how to use it I didn't understand what the benefit of it ?

3- I there way to handler to render global template tags to use in more than template ?

4- I'm using MongoEngine will it work with tornado asynchronous or I have to use Asyncmongo ?

Comment: That's four questions. It's a bit easier for people to answer one at a time, so it's nice if you split them up.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't know much about this one, but you could either to AJAX calls to twitter on the frontend, or do something like this: http://arstechnica.com/open-source/guides/2010/04/tutorial-use-twitters-new-real-time-stream-api-in-python.ars
2. UIModules are reusable parts of a site which can be easily inserted into any template. E.g, you could have a post module and a comment module in a blog, which you could then reuse on multiple pages.
3. Not really.
4. Use `asyncmongo`.

Comment: I found this one twitter stream using ioloop
https://github.com/joshmarshall/tweetstream

Comment: is there a quickstart or documentation for asyncmongo

Comment: I'm not aware of any good tutorials, but the basics are on [their github README](https://github.com/bitly/asyncmongo/blob/master/README.md) and they try to use the same API as pymongo (who have [some decent documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html))